# Facebook sdk error : Cross-site request forgery validation failed. The "state" param from the URL and session do not match

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

Anyone why i got this error? I am trying to log-in via Facebook.

It give me this error:

> Cross-site request forgery validation failed. The "state" param from
>   the URL and session do not match.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code!

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

```
$this->facebook['callback_url'] = Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl('users/user/set-info') . '&social_code=21g36fsdfe135e5';
    $this->facebook['login_url'] = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://example.com/index.php?r=users/user/set-info&social_code=21g36fsdfe135e5', $this->facebook['permissions']);

    try {
      // Get the Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser object for the current user.
      // If you provided a 'default_access_token', the '{access-token}' is optional.
      $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      // When Graph returns an error
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      // When validation fails or other local issues
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }

    if (isset($accessToken)) {

        $this->setUserData([
            'facebook' => [
                'access_token' => (string) $accessToken
            ]
        ]);  

        // OAuth 2.0 client handler
        $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

        // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
        $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;

        // setting default access token to be used in script
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);          

        $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=email,id,name,first_name,last_name,link,gender,locale,timezone,updated_time,verified,location,friends', $accessToken);
        $tmp = $response->getGraphObject();

        echo 'Logged in as ' . $tmp->getName();

        $this->user_information = [
            'social_id' => $tmp['id'],
            'social_name' => 'facebook',
            'email' => $tmp['email'],
            'public_profile' => $tmp['link'],
            'first_name' => $tmp['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $tmp['last_name'],
            'gender' => $tmp['gender'],
            'home_address' => $tmp['location']['name'],
            'user_friends' => $tmp['friends'],
        ];

        $friends_response = $fb->get('/me/taggable_friends?fields=id,name,picture,email&limit=5000', $accessToken);
        $temp = $friends_response->getGraphEdge();


        $friends = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($temp); ++$i) {
            $friends[] = $temp[$i];
        }

        $_SESSION['friends'] = $friends;

        $this->social_loggedIn = true;
    } 
    else {
        $this->social_loggedIn = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Go to the file

src/Facebook/PersistentData/PersistentDataFactory.php

In Your Facebook SDK

find this Code

```html
if ('session' === $handler) {
           new FacebookSessionPersistentDataHandler();
 
          }
```

And Replace with

```html
if ('session' === $handler) {
              return new FacebookSessionPersistentDataHandler();
          }
```

Comment: do you added you domain on the facebook application Control Panel?

Comment: Please check Edited Solution

Comment: there is no PersistentDataFactory.php file under PersistentData folder

Comment: Make sure you enter the same website URL in the app settings and in the script and once you are done with this then remove the app from your Facebook account settings and then close all tabs and browser then try again.